# vscode let all my file have changed scripts of launch.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, launch

I would like to add two scripts("debugOptions": ["RedirectOutput"],"console": "none") into launch.json like below. However, when I create a new file, this setting would become default again. How can I set to let my every new file have these two scripts ?

```
"version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",

        "debugOptions": ["RedirectOutput"],
        "console": "none"
    },
```

Comment: are you building your project again after change in json?

Comment: yes, I started a new project but without  two scripts I needed.